# sql: my data repeats itself

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: BUG]

When I execute my code it works but my data repeats itself. The print is just to see what it gets.

```
DECLARE @Variable1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Variable2 NVARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @Variable3 NVARCHAR(MAX)

CREATE TABLE #Temp1 (MAI_ID BIGINT, FUN_ID BIGINT)
CREATE TABLE #tmp2 (MAI_ID BIGINT, Variable1 NVARCHAR(MAX),Variable2 NVARCHAR(MAX), Variable3 NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO #Temp1
SELECT TOP 10 ISD_MainID, ISNULL(ISD_FUNID,0)
FROM [dev_SAB_EM].[dbo].[SiteDetails]
ORDER BY ISD_ID DESC

DECLARE @MAI_ID BIGINT 
DECLARE @FUN_ID BIGINT

 WHILE (SELECT COUNT(MAI_ID) FROM #Temp1) <> 0
 BEGIN
SELECT TOP 1 @MAI_ID = MAI_ID, @FUN_ID = FUN_ID FROM #Temp1
PRINT @MAI_ID
PRINT @FUN_ID
SELECT @Variable1 = ISNULL(FUN_Name,'') FROM [dev_SAB_Man].[dbo].[fx_GetFUNStructureCTE_Asc] (@FUN_ID) WHERE FUN_Level = 1
SELECT @Variable2 = ISNULL(FUN_Name,'') FROM [dev_SAB_Man].[dbo].[fx_GetFUNStructureCTE_Asc] (@FUN_ID) WHERE FUN_Level = 2
SELECT @Variable3 = ISNULL(FUN_Name,'') FROM [dev_SAB_Man].[dbo].[fx_GetFUNStructureCTE_Asc] (@FUN_ID) WHERE FUN_Level = 3

INSERT INTO #tmp2(MAI_ID, Variable1, Variable2, Variable3) 
SELECT @MAI_ID, @Variable1, @Variable2, @Variable3 

DELETE FROM #Temp1 WHERE MAI_ID = @MAI_ID AND FUN_ID = @FUN_ID
  END

  SELECT * FROM #tmp2

DROP TABLE #Temp1
DROP TABLE #tmp2
```

---

### fx_GetFUNStructureCTE_Asc

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fx_GetFUNStructureCTE_Asc] (@param_FUNID int)
RETURNS @FUN_Names table 
(
    [Level_Label] nvarchar(255),
    [FUN_Name] nvarchar(255),
    [FUN_Level] int, 
    [FUN_ID] int
)
AS
BEGIN
with cte([Level_Label],[FUN_Name],[FUN_Level],[FUN_ID],[FUN_FUNID]) as
(
    select ful1.FUL_Name,fu1.FUN_Name,fu1.FUN_Level,fu1.FUN_ID,fu1.FUN_FUNID
    from FunctionalUnits fu1
    inner join FunctionalUnitLevels ful1 on ful1.FUL_Level=fu1.FUN_Level
    where fu1.FUN_ID=@param_FUNID
    union all
    select ful2.FUL_Name,fu2.FUN_Name,fu2.FUN_Level,fu2.FUN_ID,fu2.FUN_FUNID
    from FunctionalUnits fu2
    inner join FunctionalUnitLevels ful2 on ful2.FUL_Level=fu2.FUN_Level
    inner join CTE a on a.FUN_FUNID=fu2.FUN_ID
)

    insert into @FUN_Names
    ([Level_Label],[FUN_Name],[FUN_Level],[FUN_ID])
    (select [Level_Label],[FUN_Name],[FUN_Level],[FUN_ID] from cte 
        where exists (select FUA_isActive from FunctionalUnitsActive where FUA_isActive=1))

return
RETURN
END
```

GO

Any suggestions or anything that can hep me?
Ok I've added fx_GetFUNStructureCTE_Asc

Comment: Well, that would depend on your function (`[dev_SAB_Man].[dbo].[fx_GetFUNStructureCTE_Asc]`) actually returning different values. So without looking at some sample data **and** the code of your function we can't really help much

Comment: ive added the fx_GetFUNStructureCTE_Asc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the informations you gave, besides what @Lamak said, it also may depend on what the the field `ISD_FUNID` values has on `[dev_SAB_EM].[dbo].[SiteDetails]` table. If they are all the same on every record then there's no problem with your code...

But, it's a basic assumption...

And, assuming what you said on your comment as the value of `ISD_FUNID` being `NULL`, what may be happening is this: *when all the value of the field `FUN_ID` are `0` on table `#Temp1` what will happen when you execute the query on the function `[dev_SAB_Man].[dbo].[fx_GetFUNStructureCTE_Asc]` is that all rows will loop while the assignment occurs, setting the variables values to the last one returned by the function.*

It'll make all the variables values be the same for all `#tmp2` rows. You may need to improve the function call to return just one value.

Comment: By empty you mean 'NULL'?